# Google Sites "addListItem" fails with Google Form Prefilled URL

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-sites

I am working up a solution which returns a link to a prefilled Google Form, to be located on a classic Google Sites List Page. I have all the code in place, everything works, aside from the last vital part: programmatically, via Google Apps Script, adding the Google Form prefilled url as a new listitem on a Google Sites List Page. I am doing the prefilling using variables from a spreadsheet (the Responses from the google form). The url/anchor code looks perfectly formed in the Log. Here is the code:

```
//fetch all spreadsheet row entries to variables
var keyname = candname;
var keytimestamp = ActiveSheet.getRange("A"+ActiveRow).getValue();
var keytimestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var keyinc01 = ActiveSheet.getRange("B"+ActiveRow).getValue();
var keyinc02 = ActiveSheet.getRange("C"+ActiveRow).getValue();
var keyinc03 = ActiveSheet.getRange("D"+ActiveRow).getValue();
var keybrok01 = ActiveSheet.getRange("E"+ActiveRow).getValue();
var keybrok02 = ActiveSheet.getRange("F"+ActiveRow).getValue();
var keybrok03 = ActiveSheet.getRange("G"+ActiveRow).getValue();
var keyacc01 = ActiveSheet.getRange("H"+ActiveRow).getValue();
var keyacc02 = ActiveSheet.getRange("I"+ActiveRow).getValue();
var keyacc03 = ActiveSheet.getRange("J"+ActiveRow).getValue();




 //var prefillurl = "https://www.google.co.uk"; //test other url

var prefillurl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/xxxxxxxx.org/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfOT0CVpSyGrlZmKKIRVCqbg11rAa9ANyYL8u9QwIWjqWfITg/viewform?entry.1894338678='+keyinc01+'&entry.1429410229='+keyinc02+'&entry.868549131='+keyinc03+'&entry.1083479546='+keybrok01+'&entry.1385475363='+keybrok02+'&entry.137722395='+keybrok03+'&entry.1074722805='+keyacc01+'&entry.1093081320='+keyacc02+'&entry.409101030='+keyacc03;  


var listpageurl = "<a href="+"'"+prefillurl+"'"+">Google Form Link</a>";

 Logger.log(listpageurl);   


 var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/xxxxxxxx.org/xxxxxxxx");

 var page = site.getChildByName("/home/candidates/"+candwebname);

 page.addListItem([ keytimestamp, ssname, listpageurl ]);
```

As you can see I have tested the anchor tag syntax with the commented "https://www.google.co.uk", which works, and the prefilled url pasted into a browser also works correctly (grabbed from the Log). Also the listpage will accept the url via manual direct entry.However I always get the error about the anchor tag not being properly formed when I run the code. I have also tested with and without the https:// in the url, just in case. I have either missed something fundemental, have left out some additional quotes or double quotes, or have found a bug?

I have found a workaround, which was to enable UrlShortener, but would prefer to be able to use the prefilled url directly ( I will have a lot of these to do!) to speed things up, and make the code more transferrable.

Can anyone spot the issue here?